# ビジュアルプログラミングが Android スマホで操作できない

Tags: aibo-visual-programming

ソニーの aibo Visual Programming がスマホに対応したとのことですが、
AU の BASIO (Android 7.1.2) では以下のようになり操作ができません。

PCであれば、表示されていない場所へのドラッグが出来ます。

なにか方法があるのでしょうか？あるいは、BASIO に対応してないのでしょうか？
お教えください。サポートさんに伺ったら、こちらで質問するように言われましたので、
よろしくお願いいたします。（aibo関係は最新バージョンです。）

**スマホでの表示:**

[image]

**PCでの表示:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単純に画面解像度の問題な気がします。参考までに、Q&Aには以下の通り記載されています。
(特に関連しそうな箇所のみ抜粋)。

端末を横向きにしたり、Chrome を使っている場合は「PC版サイト」での表示を試してみてください。

[aibo ビジュアルプログラミング](https://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/)

> Q : スマートフォンやタブレットでも使えますか？
>
> スマートフォンなどの小さい画面での操作が難しい場合、横画面表示やChromeの「PC版サイト表示」をご利用いただくことで操作しやすくなる場合があります。
> その他の動作環境につきましては、下記の通りです。
>
> - Android 8.0 以降の場合 : Google Chrome

Comment: 早速のご回答をありがとうございます。「PC版サイト表示」でなく「PC版サイト」で構わなかったのですね。お陰様でBASIO でも使えそうだと判って安心しました。ただ、もの凄く小さく、指では難しいので、ペンを買ってきて試してみます。
最悪、ＰＣで作ってスマホに読み込み、実行してみます。